# Bootstrap/HTML - Clarification

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm following the example at http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-vertical-tab. I'm not quite able to figure out how to modify the size of the arrow mark that points towards the right when a menu item is selected.

Could I please request help to identify the element in question in the CSS?

Comment: Have a look in your inspector and play with this class: `div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a.active:after`

Comment: Honestly don't understand why this question has been marked down. What about this question sounds dumb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open ::after inside `<a>` element. And then you can change the value of borders.

for example

```
 div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a.active:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -13px;
    border-left: 0;
    border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
    border-top: 13px solid transparent;
    border-left: 57px solid #5A55A3;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to change the margin-top too to vertical align the arrow (change it too the same value as your border size, but then negative)

Answer (score 1):

Change border value according to your needed.

CSS:

```
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group > a.active::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -13px;  //change as your needed
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent; //change as your needed
  border-top: 13px solid transparent;  //change as your needed
  border-left: 10px solid #5A55A3;  //change as your needed
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to change the margin-top too to vertical align the arrow (change it too the same value as your border size, but then negative)

Comment: Sure Tirzno. Thank you